# Content of $\mathbb N$

Tags: logic, set-theory

I am working with the following set of axioms:

1) There is a set.

2) Two sets are equal iff they contain equal elements.

3) if $A$ is a set and $p(x)$ is a set property (e.g. $x = x$), then $\{a \in A : p(a)\}$ is also a set.

4) if $A$ and $B$ are sets, then there is a set which contains only elements of $A$ and $B$.

5) if $\mathbb A$ a set, then $\{a | \exists A \in \mathbb A : a \in A\}$ is also a set.

6) For each set there is its power set.

7) There is an inductive set, i.e. the one which contains $\emptyset$ and if it contains $a$, then it also contains $a^+:=a\cup\{a\}$.

With these axioms I can prove a theorem: There is one and only one inductive set which is subset of any other inductive set. This inductive set I call $\mathbb N$ (the proof of existence is not constructive, so we do not know how $\mathbb N$ looks like).

I introduce the following notations: $0:=\emptyset,1:=0^+,2:=1^+,...$

I would like to show that $\mathbb N = \{0,1,2,3,4,...\}$, i.e. in $\mathbb N$ we have **only** elements "derived" from $\emptyset$.

**My attempt**

First of all it is not clear that $\{0,1,2,3,4,...\}$ is a set. I prove it as follows: $\{0,1,2,3,4,...\}=\{a \in \mathbb N : a = \emptyset^{+^{.^{.^{.^{+}}}}} \}$ and according to 3) $\{0,1,2,3,4,...\}$ is a set. (not sure whether this step is correct, specifically whether $a = \emptyset^{+^{.^{.^{.^{+}}}}}$ can be used as a set property).

Then it is obvious that $\{0,1,2,3,4,...\}$ is inductive and $\subset \mathbb N$, thus $\{0,1,2,3,4,...\} = \mathbb N$ (according to the theorem).

My introduction in the set theory was rather informal, so I would also need an informal answer (a formal one I probably would not be ably to comprehend).

Comment: As I see it, it is a recursive definition: two sets are equal if they have equal elements, two elements (i.e. also sets, what else? there is nothing else apart from sets in the math universe (at least my professor claims so)) are equal if they have equal elements, and so on.

Comment: @SergeyZykov: Note that the axiom system you quote is the standard presentation of the set theory Z, which is a minor variant of [Zermelo's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo_set_theory), except for not havin the Axiom of Choice. (The numbering of the axioms is not standardized, though).

Comment: Pretty sure you misstated the 4th axiom (pairing, I presume).

Comment: How do you even know that $\{0,1,2\ldots\}$ is a set? Based on what axiom?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: As far as I can see, that is the question being asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to show that $\mathbb N = \{0,1,2,3,4,...\}$, i.e. in $\mathbb N$ we have **only** elements "derived" from $\emptyset$.

Assuming that you're working in ordinary first-order logic, you **cannot** show that, because it **is not necessarily true**. More precisely, there *exist models* of your axiom system where there is an object that *is* in every inductive set, but *is not* one of $0,1,2,3\ldots$.

Unfortunately, the proof that such models exist is quite non-constructive, and it is not easy to display a *particular* model with this property. It has to exist, due to the *compactness principle* and Gödel's completeness theorem, but its structure is not straightforwardly describable.

Your attempt to prove that $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ is a set using the separation axiom fails because "is one of $0, 0^+, 0^{++}, \ldots$" is not something you can write down as a finite formula in the language of set theory.

One caveat, though: If you're not using first-order logic but *second-order* logic, you have the option of formulating the separation axiom with a formal quantification over all properties $p$ (instead of just having one instance of the axiom for each property *that you can write down*), then the models I'm talking about here are not actually models. You would then be able to prove as a *metatheorem* that in every model, every element of $\mathbb N$ has the form $0^{++\,\cdots\,++}$. (This would still not be a statement in the language of set theory, though).

However, set theory is rarely done in second-order logic, for a variety of reasons. (The most immediate one is that second-order logic is not *complete*: there can be sentences that are true in every model but still not provable from the axioms).

Comment: How then a proof by induction can work? I prove that $0$ has a property, then I prove, that if $0^{+...+}$ has the property, then so does $0^{+...++}$, and from that I conclude that $\mathbb N$ has the property. But if waht you are saying is true, then the conclusion for the whole $\mathbb N$ is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: @SergeyZykov: You can use induction to prove any property _that you can actually write down in the language of the theory_. The property of being one of $0, 0^+, 0^{++}, \ldots$ is just not one of those.

Comment: I am afraid you have misunderstood me. I mean if $\mathbb N$ contains more than $\{0,1,2,3,4,...\}$, then when I use induction I actually show that something is true for $\{0,1,2,3,4,...\}$, but not necessarily for $\mathbb N$, right?

Comment: @SergeyZykov: No -- induction shows that something is true for $\mathbb N$, (as long as it's something you can write down and use in the separation axiom) -- because if it were _not_ true for all of $\mathbb N$, the subset of $\mathbb N$ that it _is_ true for would be an inductive set that is smaller than $\mathbb N$, contradicting $\mathbb N$ being the smallest.

Comment: Let's says that $p(x)$ is a set property, define $A:=\{x \in \mathbb N | p(x)\}$, say we can show that $p(0)$ and $p(0^{+...+}) \implies p(0^{+...++})$, then $\{0,1,2,3,...\} \subset A$, but it does not mean that $A$ inductive and thus $=\mathbb N$, does it?

Comment: @SergeyZykov: $p(0)$ and $\forall x(p(x)\to p(x^+))$ is exactly the definition of inductive. If you can only show $p(x)\to p(x^+)$ under the assumption that $x$ is a numeral, then you would have a problem, but that sounds unlikely, given that (as I've harped upon many times now) the assumption "is a numeral" is not even something you can _state_ during a proof!